# How can I make a process with standard-user privileges to authenticate a user entered system credentials on MacOS 10.9?

Tags: macos, security, osx-mavericks

I have to authenticate a user entered system username and password in a custom UI, presented during the installation of my software on Mac OSx 10.9
Is there a direct way to do so?

AuthorizationCreate from "Authorization.h" seems to authenticate only for admin user credentials and not standard user credentials. Any help in this matter would be appreciated.

Comment: why do you want to authenticate standard user?

Comment: The software, as intended, can be installed by any user, and not just admin users.

Answer (score 2):

You start with AuthorizationCreate to give you an AuthorizationRef. Using that, call AuthorizationCopyRights with the rights you want to obtain.

Your program can check to see if the rights it is going to test is in the Authorization database and if not, it should add them. Depending upon what rights you want, you can set the rules to request the credentials of just the current user and not an administrator.

It's all explained, with code in Apple's docs [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/security/Conceptual/authorization_concepts/03authtasks/authtasks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000995-CH206-BCIGEHDI).

Comment: Hi Merlin069, Could you explain a bit more about the part where the program can check to see if the rights is in the Authorization database? I am doing the rest of the stuff in exactly the same way. I couldn't find any help regarding this in the documentation.

Comment: Calling AuthorizationCopyRights brings up the Security Authorization dialog for you. This is a separate application, by Apple, which talks to a security daemon (securityd) and handles checking the database for you. If you need help with a specific issue, I suggest you start a new question, show the code of what you're doing and explain what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: By using the flag kAuthorizationFlagInteractionAllowed in the AuthorizationFlags parameter of AuthorizationCopyRights, OS will pop up a Authorization dialog and upon entering Admin credentials there, standard users are authenticated. Is there anyway to bypass the Security Authorization dialog?

Comment: What do you mean by 'bypass the Security Authorization dialog'? If you don't call it, it won't display.

Comment: Never mind. Running the process as a sudo user and including the flag kAuthorizationFlagInteractionAllowed didn't pop up the security authorization dialog but it successfully authenticated any username and password passed as AuthorizationItems to AuthorizationCopyRights.